# Transfoming jQuery eye pupil tracker with mousemove event

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Purpose of my code is to make the eye pupil to follow user's cursor direction. Here's the code i was following: https://codepen.io/J-Roel/pen/wWGNQN, but it is written in jQuery, so i've converted it to a vanilla js:

```
eyeHandler(event) {
  let eye = this.$refs.eye
  let x = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().left) + (eye.clientWidth / 2)
  let y = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().top) + (eye.clientHeight / 2)
  let rad = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y)
  let rot = (rad * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180
  eye.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)'
  eye.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)'
  eye.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)'
  eye.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)'
}
```

This is where i've added event listener:

```
created() {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.eyeHandler)
}
```

But it's not working as expected:

1. When i move my cursor to the right, the pupil goes down very slowly.
2. When i move left, it goes up.

Guess, i've converted the code the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.move-area').forEach(function(ele) {
    ele.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        var eye = document.querySelectorAll(".eye");
        var x = (eye[0].offsetLeft) + (eye[0].offsetWidth / 2);
        var y = (eye[0].offsetTop) + (eye[0].offsetHeight / 2);
        var rad = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
        var rot = (rad * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180;
        eye.forEach(function(ele) {
            ele.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)';
            ele.style['-moz-transform'] = 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)';
            ele.style['-ms-transform'] = 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)';
            ele.style['transform'] = 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)';
        });
    });
})
```

```css
.move-area{/*normally use body*/
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 10% 45%;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.eye {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #CCC;
}
.eye:after { /*pupil*/
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 17px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: " ";
}
```

```html
<section class="move-area">
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='eye'></div>
        <div class='eye'></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I've added event listener to a window object, could be that an issue? Because even with your code i'm getting the same result:

Comment: in plain js you need to add event listener to the related elements: eyes...

Comment: if you are using vue.js the event handler must be added using vuejs

Comment: Why i must attach event listener to `eyes`? Shouldn't it listen for whole window, because cursor is moving across the window.

Comment: `class='.container'` should be `class='container'`

Comment: Ah, didn't check the codepen. I would copy the same thing :)